# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android

I have a main app which has a dependency to a android libary. I have an activity in android library. I verified the layout file and activity class. Activity class is make a call to right layout file. But I don't know for some reason, I am not able to call the library's activity from main app. Dependency wise, I verified everything. I have another library as well which main app depend on but that library works gr8 without any issues. For this library, I keep getting,

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03001a
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2451)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5499)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03001a
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2656)
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1082)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                      at XXXXXXXXXXXX.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1117)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2451) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5499) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
```

Answer (score 0):

I imported package specific R file in activity and issue gone. Thanks for everyone for your time.﻿